Client-side Routing in Nginx
I'm building a docker image and the React app routing is not working. When I click on the "/about" route, it gives the "404 Not Found in nginx/1.27.1 error". It works fine with npm start. I'm using React-Router V6.
Here is my docker file:
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .

RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

#COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Here is my nginx.conf file:
# nginx.conf
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;
  
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  #gzip  on;
  #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }  
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';
}
}

Here is my client-side routing:
return (
  <div>
    <NavigationBar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Hero />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="/services" element={<Services />} />
      <Route path="/team" element={<Team />} />
      </Routes>
  </div>
);

How do I go about making the routing work? I'm hoping to solve the the routing error.

I have managed to solve it.
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

